# catch errors for getting an instance of a smart contracts using address`in solidity

Tags: solidity, try-catch

I tried to use the `try / catch` expression in order to catch errors while getting an instance of a running smart contract but `it can only be used for external functions calls and contract creation calls`

The type of construct error i would like to catch is similar to the following code snippet.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract A {

    constructor() {
    }
}

contract B {
    A public contractA;
    constructor() {
    }

    function getContractA(address _addressOfA) public {
        contractA = A(_addressOfA /* catching error for invalid addresses */);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not possible. The assignment `contractA = A(_addressOfA)` will succeed for any value of `_addressOfA`. Solidity doesn't implement any type checking on runtime, only at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solidity only type-checks that if the value passed in complies with the type `address` but won't check if an address is of a certain contract/type since the compiler can't reach out to the blockchain/query contracts.

It's simply because as
[@Ismael](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/2124/ismael) commented,

> Solidity doesn't implement any type checking on runtime, only at compile time.

If you wish to build this functionality, then the target contract should have a callable function like `isContractA` and should return some known value like a hash of all it's methods that the caller can validate.